# Post format or Type for List Type Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, post-formats

I want to create a post type / format where I can create list type posts... For example...

```
h1.Title: The List Post Title like "Best Salads..."
- Intro paragraph
h2. Best Veg Salads
- Intro
-- h3. Salad #1
-- h3. Salad #2
..
-- h3. Salad #X

h2. Best Non-Veg Salads
- Intro
-- h3. NV Salad #1
-- h3. NV Salad #2
..
-- h3. MV Salad #X
..
..
h2. Best XYZ Salads
- Intro
-- h3. Salad #1
-- h3. Salad #2
..
-- h3. Salad #X

Footer text...
```

Essentially each entry is a text field. 
So I should be able to add any number of headings and subheadings in the post edit screen.

Note: I am not trying to create a post-type as salad. Salad is an example of one of the many published list posts. I am trying to create a site where I can post list type posts...

How can I achieve this.... Any ideas and suggestions would be great...

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use `register_post_type` and `register_taxonomy` to do so:

```
function add_cpt_salads(){
    $labels = array(
        'name'                          => __( 'Salads', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'singular_name'                 => __( 'Salad', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'menu_name'                     => __( 'Salads', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'all_items'                     => __( 'All Salads', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'add_new'                       => _x( 'Add new', 'Salads', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'add_new_item'                  => __( 'Add New Salad', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'edit_item'                     => __( 'Edit Salad', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'new_item'                      => __( 'New Salad', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'view_item'                     => __( 'View Salad', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'search_items'                  => __( 'Search Salad', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'not_found'                     => __( 'Not found', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'            => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'your-text-domain' )
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                         => __( 'Salads', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'labels'                        => $labels,
        'description'                   => __( 'Salad items', 'your-text-domain' ),
        'public'                        => true,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'publicly_queryable'        => true,
            'show_ui'                   => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'         => true,
                'show_in_menu'          => true,
                    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
                    'menu_position'     => 5,
        'capability_type'               => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'                  => true,
        'hierarchical'                  => false,
        'supports'                      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb'          => 'fjn_salads_register_meta_box',
        'taxonomies'                    => array( 'salads_category', 'salads_tag' ),
        'has_archive'                   => true,
        'query_var'                     => true,
        'can_export'                    => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'salads', $args );
    register_taxonomy(
        'salads_category',
        'salads',
        array(
            'label'                     => __( 'Salads category', 'your-text-domain' ),
            'rewrite'                   => array( 'slug' => 'salad_cat' ),
            'hierarchical'              => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_cpt_salads', 0 );
```

### UPDATE

You should add the above snippet to your current theme's `functions.php` file.

Then you should go to Wordpress admin and under **Salads** menu, add:

- Best Veg Salads
- Best Non-Veg Salads
- ...
- Best XYZ Salads

using **Add Salad category** submenu.

Then add:

- Salad #1
- Salad #2
- ...
- Salad #x

using **Add New Salad** submenu, and choose categories for them.

Now in the root directory of your current theme, create a new file named `page-salads.php` and put this in it:

```
$terms = get_terms( 'salads_category' );
foreach( $terms as $term ){
    $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy='salads_category'&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=-1" );
    if( $posts->have_posts() ){?>
        <h2><?php echo $term;?></h2><?php
        while( $posts->have_posts() ){
            $posts->the_post();
            $the_title();
            //Do you general query loop here ...
        }  
    }
}
```

Then in Wordpress admin, go to **Pages** and add a page, named **Salads**, and take care of the slug to be as:

```
http://{your-home-url}/salads
```

like:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/salads
```

and save. Then go to **Settings>Permalinks** and hit the **Save changes** button and in your browser enter the following URL:

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/salads
```

That is all.

Comment: Note: I am not trying to create a post-type as salad. Salad is one of the list posts. I am trying to create a site where I can post list type posts...

Comment: Please note the first sentence in your question: `I want to create a post type`. So what?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to post type / post formats... Essentially, I am want to create a Top 10 list kind of post... where each entry is editble. hope you understand

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use the default blog posts / custom post type and make use of the [custom taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and create a hierarchy of your list types.

You can then achieve your page by using a shortcode to pull in your categories ( Salads) and children (Best Non-Veg Salads) .

Within your shortcode you could use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)